# CSS transition display: block

Tags: jquery, html, css

I looked at other subject and I did the same : add padding, height, opacity.

But I have no transition with the css above. Can you tell me why ?

When I touch a button it adds the class .show to my div contactEmote :

```
#contactEmote{
    display: none;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: #f65b61;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2000;

    opacity:0;
    clear: both;
    height: 0px;
    padding: 0 8px;
    overflow: hidden;

    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    transition: all .3s ease .15s;


    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 35px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.68);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 35px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.68);
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 35px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.68);
}

#contactEmote.show{
    top: 0px;
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot transition elements if you are toggling `display` between `block` and `none`. Try changing those rules to `visibility: hidden` and `visibility: visible`.

Comment: but the div will still take place where it is no ? I mean it is invisible but I can't put something more

Comment: Do you mean that it still generally takes up space? Yes. But as you are animating height from 0 -> 100px, and have `overflow: hidden`, you may not need to use `visibility` either.